# Does Entity Framework support Oracle 10g?

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, oracle10g

Is there any way to use Entity Framework with oracle 10g? 
I am trying to create an entity model but i cannot see a data source for oracle.
Appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sort of. EF is a standard interface. You need to install a provider first.

Entity Framework is implemented via interface implementations by providers for each specific database. You have to find a provider for Oracle. One I use is Devart dotConnect. You should also be able to use Oracle's latest 12c managed provider with 10g. I typically develop across 10g - 12c databases with a single client and toolset and have no compatibility issues using 11g or 12c providers against 10g. If you are unsure, Oracle publishes a compatibility matrix of client versions to server versions.

http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Entity Framework, does not, within itself, implement support for Oracle, you must reference the appropriate assemblies that include an EF provider.

Same goes for Linq to SQL.

You may find multiple EF providers for a given database platform.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ODP installed? 
Found at:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html